# javascript search function for images in a current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new in building a HTML website but I do not have a basic programming knowledge. I put 100 animated images to other server and I link all those images into my HTML website.For example:

```
<p>
  <img src="http://.../abc/23118465.gif" alt="teddy bear"align="left" width="150" height="100" >
</p>
```

How do I write a java script search to filter the images in the current HTML pages? For example, when I type"teddy bear" in the search bar and click the image button search, it will query and search the teddy bear image from that server? Is it difficult to write those code because I try to make a drop down list to select and link those image but still don't work.

Comment: Can you describe _"but still don't work"_?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this quite easily using the [attribute contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector. You can build the selector by appending the value of a text box when a button is clicked, like this:

```js
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); 
  $('p img').hide();
  $('p img[alt*="' + $('#search').val() + '"]').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="search" />
  <button id="go"> Search</button>
</form>
<p>
  <img src="http://.../abc/23118465.gif" alt="teddy bear" align="left" width="150" height="100">
</p>
<p>
  <img src="http://.../abc/23118465.gif" alt="grizzly bear" align="left" width="150" height="100">
</p>
<p>
  <img src="http://.../abc/23118465.gif" alt="polar bear" align="left" width="150" height="100">
</p>
```

Comment: What occurs if `.val()` does not match an `alt` attribute?

Comment: Then all the images are hidden